# Is SharedPreferences useless now?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'd like to know if it's a good idea to create my app with SharedPreferences while it has been depreciated. It's really sad, it was a very simple and elegant way to save small paramters, I read about Preference Datastore but it seem very complicated compared to it. If I still use SharedPreferences does it mean that my app is obsolete for new androids version? And what is the best alternative to it?

Thanks

Comment: Any answer to this question will be opinion based ... having said that, useless is strong word to put in here .. I don't think its going to be useless ... as you mentioned already it is easy to setup shared prefs compared to datastore ... but according to me `Anything that makes a developer life easy will not go useless unless there is something else which is more easy`

Comment: Is there any official documentation on the deprecation of SharedPreference?

Comment: @Zain good question, I am using SharedPrefs on my Android-Kotlin App and it is not yet deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharedPreferences is not deprecated.

Preference (the settings screen UI element) and PreferenceManager are deprecated in favor of the Jetpack Preferences library, which works almost exactly the same way and still uses SharedPreferences directly.

Import `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0` in your dependencies and import the `androidx` version of PreferenceManager and PreferenceFragment to use it without deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin users add

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
```

inside the app-level `build.gradle` file, then Sync.

And update your import:

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
```

Then that deprecated warning will be gone.